# Adding com.jdbc.odbc.Driver via terminal

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc-odbc

when i try to run a project

```
java -jar test.jar
```

i get the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver                    
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

how to add mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar in classpath

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have forget to add the library in your project. Please see the links below

- [Adding a library (.jar) to your project](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath)
- [MySQL and Java JDBC - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)

Comment: how to add library (.jar) to the project??

Answer (score 1):

You should be having jdbc driver classes in your classpath.

Comment: Akash, This link will help you. [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)